Cypress Iframe - Can not Access "done" Button
I've successfully uploaded an image but can not access the "done" button in the iframe.
There are multiple iframes on the page so I can not use cy.iframe(). Even calling the "nth" iframe will not let me access the elements in that particular iframe.
So I've tried a custom command.
//Click Add Photos 
cy.contains('Add Photos').click({force: true}, {multiple:true})

//Upload photo 
cy.get('.css-1jk49jo .dropzone--isActive').selectFile('cypress/fixtures/RedPanda.jpg', {action: "drag-drop"})

//Get iFrame and wrap
cy.getIframeDocument = ()=> {
   return cy.get('iframe[data-test="uw-iframe"]')
     .its('0.contentDocument').should('not.exist')
     .then(cy.wrap()) }

//Click Done
cy.getIframeDocument().find('.bg-action-c')

Even with a custom command I get the following TypeError
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

1
How can I .click()on that button inside the iframe?

If you look at the cypress-iframe docs, you can see how to specify the particular iframe you want to test inside of.
By specifying a selector (the selector same as used in cy.get()) you can pick an individual iframe from your page.
cy.iframe('[data-test="uw-iframe"]')
  .find('.some-button').should('be.visible').click()

